# How to add screen option checkbox for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

For my plugin I added a screen option with number input field. I want to add checkbox fields. Could not found out anything [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_screen_option). See the code:

```
//defined $my_admin here

add_action( 'load-' . $my_admin, "my_add_screen_options" );

//add screen options
function my_add_screen_options() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    //some checks

    $args = array(
            'label' => __('description', 'my'),
            'default' => 20,
            'option' => 'my_per_page'
    );
    add_screen_option( 'per_page', $args );
}

//Save the data from screen options
add_filter( 'set-screen-option', 'my_set_screen_option', 10, 3 );

function my_set_screen_option( $status, $option, $value ) {
    if ( 'my_per_page' == $option ) return $value;
}
```

It works for number input. I thought changing `$args` will make it display checkboxes or any other field. But could not find anything significant by google too.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Using filter hook create one option in screen option.

For example i create Thumbnail option in post list. following code add in theme function.php

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns', 5);
function posts_columns($defaults){
   $defaults['my_post_thumbs'] = __('Thumbnail');
   return $defaults;
}
```